# Getting "OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import time
import numpy as np
```

---

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-1-673eae4585a7> in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 import random
      3 import time
      4 import numpy as np

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>
    105 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    106 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 107 from . import cbook, rcsetup
    108 from matplotlib.cbook import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, sanitize_sequence
    109 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation  # deprecated

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py in <module>
     26 import weakref
     27 
---> 28 import numpy as np
     29 
     30 import matplotlib

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    136 
    137     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 138     from . import _distributor_init
    139 
    140     from . import core

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     24                 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
     25                 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 26                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     27                 DLL_filenames.append(filename)
     28         if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    379 
    380         if handle is None:
--> 381             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    382         else:
    383             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Hi, could you please more specific on where you need help and what you are hoping to achieve? You've provided a great level of detail on your code, but some explanation will help in getting an answer.

Comment: When I'm importing those packages in Jupyter Notebook, I get this OS error. I am not able to figure out the solution.